# A fool-proof tsup config for a React component library

Tags: reactjs, npm, open-source

I've never published an NPM package before. All these details to generate a package seem way too complicated to my level. The only tool, that was beginner friendly, that I could find is [create-react-library](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/create-react-library) which recommended to switch to [tsup](https://github.com/egoist/tsup) instead.

I'm asking here to know if there's a batteries-included, most-cases-met, setup for `tsup` or any other tool of your recommendation for this kind of project (and I think this is a common scenario):

- A React Project
- Typed with Typescript
- Tested with Jest
- No dependencies
- Exports React components
- Should be public on NPM

Comment: Hi, I maintain the VulcanJS framework and I have similar needs, checkout our current solution using Tsup: https://github.com/VulcanJS/vulcan-npm
This setup is NOT good at the time of writing, I need to figure out how to correctly expose each component as an isolated file in order to avoid bloating bundles. But it's a real life setup with utility packages, server, client, shared, and apps code in a monorepo.

Comment: React Bootstrap could be a good source of inspiration, it exposes cjs and ESM builds: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap
It doesn't use Tsup but just a script with Babel. However the resulting structure of the "dist" folder seems interesting.

Comment: This issue might help, tips on how to handle multiple entrypoints with Tsup (each componen being potentially its own entrypoint if you want user to be able to consume only certain components): https://github.com/egoist/tsup/issues/728

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example setup.

- First you need to bundle each component separately. You can use a glob as an entry point in Tsup.
  Keep in mind that options that works for Esbuild works for Tsup most of the time.

```
// tsup.config.ts
defineConfig([
  {
  clean: true,
  sourcemap: true,
  tsconfig: path.resolve(__dirname, "./tsconfig.build.json"),
  entry: ["./components/core/!(index).ts?(x)"],
  format: ["esm"],
  outDir: "dist/",
  esbuildOptions(options, context) {
    // the directory structure will be the same as the source
    options.outbase = "./";
    },
  },
```

- Then you'll want to have a `index.ts`, for convenience, that expose named exports. This index is sometimes referred as a "barrel" file.

```
// index.ts
// the actual file is "Button.tsx" but we still want a ".js" here
export { Button } from "./components/core/Button.js";
```

Notice the `.js` extension. ESM expects explicit extensions so it's needed in the final build.

Adding the .js doesn't seem to bother TypeScript, which stills correctly recognize the type of "Button" from `Button.tsx`. At this point I am not sure *why* it works, but it does.

Transpile this index, **without bundling**.

```
// tsup.config.ts
  {
  clean: true,
  sourcemap: true,
  tsconfig: path.resolve(__dirname, "./tsconfig.build.json"),
  entry: ["index.ts", "./components/core/index.ts"],
  bundle: false,
  format: ["esm"],
  outDir: "dist",
  esbuildOptions(options, context) {
    options.outbase = "./";
    },
  },
])
```

- Finally define your package.json as usual:

```json
  "sideEffects": false,
  "type": "module",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/index.js"
  },
```

`sideEffects` is a non-standard property targeting application bundlers like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) and [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#tree-shaking).
Setting it to false tells them that the package is safe for tree-shaking.

Now `import { Button } from "my-package"` should work as you expect, and tree-shaking and dynamic loading at app-level become possible because "Button" is bundled as its own ES module `Button.js`, and the package is marked as being side-effect free.

This is confirmed by my Webpack Bundle Analyzer in a Next app:

**Before (a single bundled index.js):**

[image]

**After (separate files means I can select more precisely my imports):**

[image]

[Final config available here](https://github.com/VulcanJS/vulcan-npm/blob/08f4ae28872149dda8bd8e8007fc929e084ca69a/packages/react-ui-lite/tsup.config.ts) (might be improved in the future)

Comment: I am naming this pattern "pizza slicing". Tree shaking is not enough for a UI or utility library, you also want to cut it with one file per component.

Comment: I think you gave OP just a banana, when they were also asking about gorilla and jungle. I mean the whole library template set up.

Comment: The jungle is in the link at the bottom: https://github.com/VulcanJS/vulcan-npm

Answer (score 2):

If you want most-cases-met, batteries-included way to make a library like that then take a look at [dts-cli](https://github.com/weiran-zsd/dts-cli). It will work but it will definitely be slower than `tsup`. I myself am in the process of switching a library with about 60 react components from `dts-cli` to `tsup` because the build time started taking too long (about a minute) on a MacBook Air M1.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually found the dts-cli library myself. So far I'm enjoying using it. I'll accept your answer once I'm ready to publish the library. I'll keep it unanswered for now, in case anyone wants to suggest something else.

Comment: Just to clarify, dts-cli is a fork of tsdx. It's not sure how well it will be maintained. So indeed Tsup is probably a better investment.

Answer (score 0):

If tsup requirement is not critical for you, I suggest to use [css-vars-hook](https://github.com/morewings/css-vars-hook) repo as a template. It’s my project set up in exact same way as you described. It successfully builds [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-vars-hook). Rollup is used instead of tsup.

So, you can just replace my code with yours. The code is placed inside `/src/lib/` and demo environment inside `/src/environment/`. Main entry point is `src/lib/index.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

In my mono repo I have shadcn-ui setup as a package. Here is my files:

here is my tsup.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig, type Options } from 'tsup'

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig((options: Options) => ({
  treeshake: true,
  splitting: true,
  // target: 'es2020',
  format: ['cjs', 'esm'], // generate cjs and esm files
  entry: [
    // '/src/index.ts',
    './lib/!(index).ts?(x)',
    './hooks/!(index).ts?(x)',
    './components/!(index).ts?(x)',
    '!./**/*.spec.*',
    '!./**/*.stories.*',
  ],
  skipNodeModulesBundle: true, // Skips building dependencies for node modules
  minify: !options.watch && env === 'production',
  bundle: false, //env === 'production',
  clean: true, // clean up the dist folder
  dts: true, // generate dts file for main module
  sourcemap: true, //env === 'production', // source map is only available in prod
  outDir: 'dist', // env === 'production' ? 'dist' : 'lib',
  tsconfig: path.resolve(__dirname, './tsconfig.json'),
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  esbuildOptions(options, context) {
    options.outbase = './'
  },
  external: ['react'],
  ...options,
  // banner: {js: '"use client";'},
}))
```

my build script in package.json

```
"build": "rimraf dist && tsup && tsc --emitDeclarationOnly --declaration",
```

key items in package.json

```
"main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.cjs",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "type": "module",
"files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/index.js",
    "./hooks": "./dist/hooks/index.js",
    "./lib": "./dist/lib/index.js",
    "./components": "./dist/components/index.js",
    "./components/accordion": "./dist/components/accordion.js",
    "./components/alert-dialog": "./dist/components/alert-dialog.js",
    "./components/alert": "./dist/components/alert.js",
    "./components/aspect-ratio": "./dist/components/aspect-ratio.js",
    "./components/avatar": "./dist/components/avatar.js",
    "./components/badge": "./dist/components/badge.js",
    "./components/button": "./dist/components/button.js",
    "./components/calendar": "./dist/components/calendar.js",
    "./components/card": "./dist/components/card.js",
    "./components/checkbox": "./dist/components/checkbox.js",
    "./components/collapsible": "./dist/components/collapsible.js",
    "./components/command": "./dist/components/command.js",
    "./components/context-menu": "./dist/components/context-menu.js",
    "./components/dialog": "./dist/components/dialog.js",
    "./components/drawer": "./dist/components/drawer.js",
    "./components/dropdown-menu": "./dist/components/dropdown-menu.js",
    "./components/form": "./dist/components/form.js",
    "./components/hover-card": "./dist/components/hover-card.js",
    "./components/input": "./dist/components/input.js",
    "./components/label": "./dist/components/label.js",
    "./components/menubar": "./dist/components/menubar.js",
    "./components/navigation-menu": "./dist/components/navigation-menu.js",
    "./components/popover": "./dist/components/popover.js",
    "./components/progress": "./dist/components/progress.js",
    "./components/radio-group": "./dist/components/radio-group.js",
    "./components/scroll-area": "./dist/components/scroll-area.js",
    "./components/select": "./dist/components/select.js",
    "./components/separator": "./dist/components/separator.js",
    "./components/sheet": "./dist/components/sheet.js",
    "./components/skeleton": "./dist/components/skeleton.js",
    "./components/slider": "./dist/components/slider.js",
    "./components/switch": "./dist/components/switch.js",
    "./components/table": "./dist/components/table.js",
    "./components/tabs": "./dist/components/tabs.js",
    "./components/textarea": "./dist/components/textarea.js",
    "./components/toast": "./dist/components/toast.js",
    "./components/toaster": "./dist/components/toaster.js",
    "./components/toggle": "./dist/components/toggle.js",
    "./components/tooltip": "./dist/components/tooltip.js"
  }
```

in my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "@myapp/ts-config/react-library.json", 
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "typeRoots": ["types", "./node_modules/@types"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    // "rootDir": "src", if you want to keep files in src dir. I had no luck with that.
    "paths": {
      "react": ["./node_modules/@types/react"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "globals.d.ts"],
  "exclude": [".turbo", "tsup.config.ts", "dist", "node_modules", "**/*.stories.ts", "**/*.stories.tsx"]
}
```